# I found this issue on the terminal

Tags: command-line, display

linker Warning: "[vdso]" unused DT entype 0x70000001 arg (nil)) (ignoring)
WARNING: linker Warning: "[vdso]" unused DT entype 0x70000001 arg (nil)) (ignoring)
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$